# Acquire the data associated with a line in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following the example by [Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245), the line is created using the data from a CSV file. So, the data is actually loaded using `d3.csv()` function. These are all fairly standard steps.

What I am struggling is to acquire the x/y axis data sets without loading again from the data file to global variables. I tried to apply `data()` method to the line path but without success, the console simply says `Array [undefined]`.

What options/methods are available to achieve this? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you include your code

Comment: Same code as Bostock's example (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245), except the file is in CSV file.

Comment: If youre just using the code from that block and simply changing the method to csv then I dont see what the problem it, unless you didnt change the data to csv (comma separated vs tab separated)

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks for the comment. I think there is a slight misunderstanding. First of all, I can generate the line chart using CSV. What I was looking for is to acquire the data (say, these two columns from the CSV file) from the line chart, without using d3.csv() function to load them into global variables.

Comment: You wouldnt have to load the data again with `d3.csv()` but I dont see how you access them without setting them as variables. They wouldnt necessarily have to be global vars, you could set them as object vars.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I also tried using d3.csv to load them into local vars, but somehow they don't exist outside the d3.csv function due to the asynchronous nature. I am a newbie to d3, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

The data associated to the line is not `undefined`. I guess you used `d3.select("path")` to select the line, which will instead select the axis, since the axis was painted before in the SVG (and the axis, of course, has no `data`).

So, to select the line, simply set its class or ID:

```
g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("id", "myLine")
```

And use `data()` as a getter:

```
console.log(d3.select("#myLine").data())
```

Here is the bl.ocks, check the console, the data is there: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/e79769c5080a4618b00b946f722d7e39

Keep in mind that, if you're trying to get the data associated to the line outside `d3.tsv` function, you'll have to **wait** until the line is painted in the SVG and, therefore, present in the DOM. This is an example using `setTimeout`, with the console.log outside `d3.tsv`:

```
setTimeout(()=>{console.log(d3.select("#myLine").data());}, 1000);
```

And the respective bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/68ec8087514ff3335d81704796a9a944

Comment: Many thanks to your explanation. The `setTimeout()` function indeed works. More interestingly, it appears to work no matter the millisecond parameter is `0.00005`, or `1` or `1000`. This makes me wondering if there is a method to determine the moment "the line is painted in the SVG and, therefore, present in the DOM".

Comment: Yes, three is: put a `console.timeEnd` at the end of the callback.